# NameError: uninitialized constant CreateCommments Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.integer :link_id
      t.text :body
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :comments, :link_id
  end
end
```

I was deploying my app to heroku and had to redo the database in Pg insteand of sqlite 3. When I migrate my database I am gettting this

```
NameError: uninitialized constant CreateCommments
```

I have been search SO all day and tried many of the solutions but to no avail. I have searched spelling errors, dropped, recreated the database. My database.yml is up to date and gem and gemlock are clean of sqlite, but it will not stop yelling at me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What version of Rails do you use? What is the full filename and path of that migration?

Comment: Right now I am using 2.2.1p85 I was trying to put an old project up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because the filename is incorrect. It has to be a timestamp with the class name then in snake case, like

```
20170602175844_create_comments.rb
```

You can of course do this manually and just change the filename, or run in the console and get a new migration

```
rails g migration create_comments
```

---

**Note:**

It doesn't *have* to be a timestamp though, that's just the way the rails rake task does it. You can also use a numerical sequence like if you create your files manually. This is just done to be able to see what migrations have already run and to be able to rollback to a specific version. Also so that the migrations run in a specific order.

```
1_create_comments.rb
```

Comment: The Migration file does have a time stamp thats why I am so confused.

Comment: What is the filename?

Comment: 20160128212901_create_commments.rb

is in my migration folder

Comment: Three 'm' there?

Comment: You sir are the man I have been beating my head against the wall for hours

Comment: Ahh, the joys of programming :) Good luck